# Update cursor for Android Search Suggestions ContentProvider asynchronously

Tags: android, android-search, android-searchmanager

I am using a `ContentProvider` to provide search suggestions for a [Searchable Configuration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) in my app.

I successfully receive `query` calls and when I create a `MatrixCursor`, add several rows, and return the cursor, they are properly displayed in the search results.

However, if I make an asynchronous network request to fetch results, then populate the same `MatrixCursor` with additional rows, these items are not populated in the search results.

I have tried calling

```
synchronized (cursor) {
    cursor.notifyAll();
}
```

after adding the additional rows, but this does not appear to produce the desired result.

What is the best practice for asynchronously providing search results by way of a network request?

Comment: you could try cursor.requery() but... it is deprecated in API level 11, are you using a SearchView ?

Comment: This is actually for search suggestions on Android TV - https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/searchable.html

Comment: Also, I think the search interface itself is what would need to requery the cursor - I'm supplying the cursor from my `ContentProvider` but I can't control what happens to it after that.

Comment: is your search invoked by a system or in your app private SearchView?

Comment: It's invoked by the System - Android TV has a centralized search view that pulls results from all apps that provide a searchable configuration + ContentProvider in the manifest.

Comment: so if you cannot use your app private SearchView (which would simplify things a lot) i think that Cursor#requery() is the thing you could try...

Comment: @dcarr622 I have got the same problem. I can't fill asynchronously the cursor which is returned by ContentProvider.query(). Did you solve this problem? That's very important for me.